# Android Dialogue with custom layout button style appcompat

Tags: android, android-layout

Currently working on an application which should even work with Android 2.2 I use the support library and its AppCompat theme for styling my UI. Although most of the UI works fine I have an AlertDialog with a custom layout including two custom buttons which are necessary as the dialogue should not be closed immediately when one of the buttons is pressed.

However, I can not find a good style for making my buttons look "corporate" with the buttons in the other dialogue ([here is a link to a screenshot of the current design](https://copy.com/fMDo8iYBcKZjnvsa) as well as [one with the desired design](https://copy.com/4mOlSu0G1yM7vYZw); I am currently not having enough reputation for posting images). Below you can find my layout defining the buttons (I have used two different styles for testing purposes).

```
<LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/txtPassword">

            <Button android:id="@+id/btnCancelLogin"
                style="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Dialog"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:text="@string/btnCancel"/>

            <Button android:id="@+id/btnLogin"
                style="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Dialog"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:text="@string/btnEnterPassword"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

I appreciate any help. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `buttonBar` style to achieve this. Just add this style to your layout items

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/txtPassword"
        style="?attr/buttonBarStyle">

        <Button android:id="@+id/btnCancelLogin"
            style="?attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:text="@string/btnCancel"/>

        <Button android:id="@+id/btnLogin"
            style="?attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:text="@string/btnEnterPassword"/>

    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: This works great on API level 19, thanks a lot. However, Android Studio shows that the minimum API required for using the style attribute is 11. Furthermore, I can not test this, as my testing device broke down yesterday.

Comment: My bad, I missed the compatibility part. However since you are using the AppCompat library you just need to remove `android:` from the styles statement. I updated my answer. That should work for your version. And if you don't have a device to test you can test on the emulator maybe?

Answer (score 0):

you also can use this library https://github.com/afollestad/material-dialogs enable you to use Material design themed dialogs across all versions of Android

Comment: Thanks. However, we are currently in the final phase of the project and therefore we can't try using this library. Nevertheless, I will try it in future projects.